# Saving an basic array inside a class public property

Tags: arrays, vb.net, class

I am wondering how to save an array inside of a class in VB.Net. This is the form code I have (it gets executed when the program loads).

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim intArr As Integer() = {5, 3, 8, 1, 4, 6}
    Dim statsObj As New StatsMachine()
    statsObj.Data = intArr
    Dim avg As Double = statsObj.Average()
    txtAvg.Text = FormatNumber(avg, 2)
    txtNumAboveAvg.Text = CStr(statsObj.NumElementsAbove(avg))
End Sub
```

I am **not allowed** to change this code (this is a problem from the book) and I am supposed to create classes so it can run.

So I created the class "StatsMachine". My first public property, Data, should take the array that is created in this code and save it. Unfortunately I can't get this to work. My code at the moment:

```
Public Class StatsMachine
    Dim sourceData As Form1
    Dim m_arr() As Integer

    Public Property Data As Integer
        Get
            Return m_arr
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Integer)
            m_arr() = sourceData.intArr()
        End Set
    End Property
End Class
```

Visual Studio says sourceData.intArr() is not found. I assume this is because I need to add another identifier when I call it. What would would this be? This actually doesn't just apply to arrays, I don't know how to call things from Form 1.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you're trying to implement the class and property behind this line of code:

```
statsObj.Data = intArr
```

Because `intArr` has been declared `As Integer()` you should make your `Data` property the same.

You'll want a class like this:

```
Public Class StatsMachine
    Private m_arr As Integer()

    Public Property Data As Integer()
        Get
            Return m_arr
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Integer())
            m_arr = value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class
```

I'm not sure if I have all my brackets exactly correct when I'm setting the array in the Data setter function (because it's VB) it may need to be `m_arr() = value`

By sure to credit me on your homework :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are trying to access data from Form1, when the code in Form1_Load is actually accessing the class you created. I'm surprised that Visual Studio didn't complain about trying to declare a variable as Form1, unless you have a class by that name somewhere.

Comment: Yep. I think that if the line `Dim sourceData As Form1` had actually been `Dim sourceData As New Form1` it would have gone into an endless recursive loop of object creation...